# Is it wrong according to Hinduism to marry a girl name Swati?

Tags: manu-smriti

Manu Smriti 3.9 says this: "A man should not marry a woman named after a constellation".
Now, Swati is a constellation.
So, is it wrong to marry a girl named Swati?

Comment: Then how will you explain Vasudeva's wife Rohini and Balarama's wife Revati?

Comment: @Surya: So, either ManuSmriti is wrong in this context. Or, Vasudeva and Balarama were wrong?

Comment: Manusmriti does not apply to all yugas.

Comment: @Rickross: Would you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @AmitSaxena, well I'm never able to put manu smriti under religious book category, anything written in sanskrit doesn't means that it is related to hinduims and talks about it.

Comment: @Mr.K Manu Smriti is the most authoritative Hindu scriptures after the Vedas. Even Vedas say whatever Manu said is medicine. The rules of Dharma Adharma are to be learnt from Manu.

Comment: The quote in the Q itself is answering it. What more do you want? @AmitSaxena